# Bash script to link networked account directories to local account directories

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, for

I'm working on a script that will create a local user account, and link local account directories to networked account directories. The only directories I would like to be created and linked are the standard directories for a newly created accounts, i.e., Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Public, and Videos. So if the network account has other directories, they would be skipped.

Here is the segment of the script written, to test my script over all.

```
for i in /home/$netAcct/ ; do
  if [ -d "$i" ]; then
    ln -s /home/$netAcct/* /home/$localAcct/
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
for i in /home/"$netAcct"/{Desktop,Documents,Downloads,Pictures,Public,Videos}
```

to look at all the standard subdirectories of `netAcct`'s home directory,
and then

```
    ln -s "$i" /home/"$localAcct"/
```